# configuration error when upload ASP project to the server

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET web application, when i upload it to the server then error message shown below:

> **Configuration Error  Description**: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message**: Unrecognized attribute '*requirePermission*'.

Source Error:

```
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="extnet" type="Ext.Net.GlobalConfig" requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2WCP.jpg]

Comment: You have errors in your config file

Comment: You should at least post the config file content; also, did you check the configuration file syntax on the documentation?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1663086.aspx?Log4Net+Configuration+in+Web+Config Check this post, see if this helps

Comment: have u checked the pool of the app against the IIS. Also please check the document in MSDN for further contents...

Comment: Check your .NET framework version on the server and your project version. Should be same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
project workgin fine in local machine, but when i upload it to the server i mee the error

Comment: How can i check and change .NET franework version on IIS server?

Comment: Phil Haccked wrote a post regarding this http://haacked.com/archive/2006/07/09/ConfiguringLog4NetWithASP.NET2.0InMediumTrust.aspx/

Comment: @abdullahokkeh, the question all are asking is simple. you have two set of the same project OK ?(locally running and hosted) First note down the ASP.NET version and IIS AppPool of the local project. Now mail / chat with your hosting provider support team requesting them that you need the application to be running the AppPool of your local machine. Also tell them your ASP.NET framework version and ask them whether they have that in their server. If no, request them to install that version in their server. Clear?